# Algorithm for a single elimination tournament where the eliminated teams also compete for remaining places

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am building an application for a tennis tournament and I want to generate the matches in order for a single elimination tournament that looks like this [Tournament Brackets](https://challonge.com/tournaments/bracket_generator?ref=J5PsgD2zxR) and the teams that gets eliminated will have to compete themselves for the remaining positions.

[image: Single elimination tournament]

To clarify, the tournament starts with a N number of teams, in the example above we have 8 teams that first compete in 2 groups A and B and will play a total of 12 matches (Round Robin) then, in the next phase, the winner of group A plays with the last team on group B and so on till we have the brackets shown from match 13 till match 16. Then the winners gets to play on the main side and the losers on the second side competing for remaining position. The way that matches are distributed on phases is like this: on the next phase, the first matches are played by losing teams, after all the losing team brackets has been played, then the winner team brackets will be played as seen above, the match no 17 an 18 are "second side" losing team matches followed by match 19 and 20 that are "main side" winner matches.

A naive algorithm that I developed in javascript in which I'm trying to achieve is an array of match phases that will tell me in order how many "second side" matches will be played then how many "main side" matches:

```
    const generateMatchesBrakets = (mainSideMatches) => {

     let matchesPlayed = [];
     let stage = 0;

    while ( parseInt(mainSideMatches) ) {
        let secondSideMatches = parseInt(secondSideMatches / 2);
        if ( matchesPlayed[stage] === undefined ) matchesPlayed[stage] = [];

        matchesPlayed[stage]['main'] = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < mainSideMatches; i++) matchesPlayed[stage]['main'].push(1);

        if (secondSideMatches) {
            let nextRound = stage + 1;

            if ( matchesPlayed[nextRound] === undefined ) matchesPlayed[nextRound] = [];
            matchesPlayed[nextRound]['second'] = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < secondSideMatches; i++) matchesPlayed[nextRound]['second'].push(1); 
        }

        mainSideMatches /= 2;
        stage++;
    }

    return matchesPlayed;

}

let teams = 8;
let n = teams / 2;

if (n % 2 !== 0) n++;

let mainTournamentBrackets = generateMatchesBrakets(n);
let secondTournamentdBrackets = [];

mainTournamentBrackets.forEach( bracket => {
    if ( bracket['second'] ) {
        let n = bracket['second'].length;
        secondTournamentdBrackets.push( generateMatchesBrakets(n) ); 
    }
})
```

The structure I'm trying to achieve for 8 teams is the following

```
(3) [Array(0), Array(0), Array(0)]
       0: [main: Array(4)]
       1: [second: Array(2), main: Array(2)]
       2: [second: Array(3 /*+ 2 from second matches*/) , main: Array(1)]
   length: 3
```

So I'm generating the next branch of second matches and the plan is to concat it with the main branch. The problems comes if I have more than 2 losing matches per brackets.

Any help and suggestion will be much appreciated !

Thank You in advance!